# Contact Us form webpart provided by Microsoft disappears

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online

In SharePoint Online Office 365, the Contact Us form Web Part provided by Microsoft that I have used for my website suddenly disappears from the page after a gap of few days/months.

This happened two times. We get the following error inplace of this Web Part:

> Web Part Error: The ContactUsPart ClientWebPart feature 378103b1-3f3dc-4h63-a350-b4edm635e576 is not installed or is not Active. Correlation ID: f385559d-f0ad-3330-0gtb-a614w2f547b3.

I added it back, but is there any permanent solution for it?